# Cómo limito la cantidad de appends?

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Tengo que hacer un `append` de un `li` pero quiero limitarlo a tres `appends` de `li` como máximo y siempre.
Probé con `.slice()` pero no obtuve resultado.

```
for (var x in mesOrdenado) {
  var valueMeses = [mesOrdenado[x], anioOrdenado[j]];
  var mesesMostrar = meses[parseInt(mesOrdenado[x])];
  $("#timeline-meses").append("<li data-value=\"" + valueMeses + "\"><a href=\"#\">" + mesesMostrar + "</a></li>");
}
```

la opcion de limitar el append con el id no me funciono tampoco:

```
for (i = valueMeses; i < 3; i++) {
  $("#timeline-meses").append("<li data-value=\"" + valueMeses + "\"><a href=\"#\">" + mesesMostrar + "</a></li>");
}
```

Comment: A que te refieres con limitar?

Comment: A mostrar unicamente 3 appends. Limite: 3

Comment: No se entiende muy bien que es lo que quieres, `.append()` es una linea de código escrita por ti, si solo quieres limitarlo a tres, escribela tres veces solo.

Comment: Explica un poco mejor lo que quieres hacer: ¿Quedarte con los 3 últimos o los 3 primeros `<li>`  de la la lista?

Comment: No. Porque estoy haciendo un append de valores que llamo desde un JSON. Si no limito el append, se hace por todos los valores que yo tenga en "mesesMostrar"

Comment: Pablo, me quiero quedar con los 3 últimos <li> de la lista.

Comment: Tienes un bucle para meter los valores? Por favor, edita la pregunta y añade algo más de contexto (y de código)

Comment: Código editado y en contexto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var mesOrdenado=[0,1,2,3,4];
var meses=['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr','May'];
var contador=0;
mesOrdenado.reverse();
for (var x in mesOrdenado) {
  var valueMeses = [mesOrdenado[x], 2017];
  var mesesMostrar = meses[parseInt(mesOrdenado[x])];
  if (contador >= 3) { break; }
  contador++;
  $("#timeline-meses").append("<li data-value=\"" + valueMeses + "\"><a href=\"#\">" + mesesMostrar + "</a></li>");
  
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timeline-meses">
</div>
```

**Si quieres que sigan el mismo orden, cambias**

```
mesOrdenado.reverse();
```

por

```
mesOrdenado = mesOrdenado.slice(meses.length-3,meses.length+1);
```

Comment: Está pidiendo los 3 últimos, no los 3 primeros. Casi lo tienes

Comment: Gracias, por la puntualización se me habia pasado :P

Comment: Muchas gracias j0se! Ahora si es correcto, valido tu respuesta.